# Angular 4 and GitHub GraphQL API

Tags: angular, graphql, github-api

At this momement I have something like that

```
return this._http.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + this.username + '/repos?client_id=' + this.client_id + '&client_secret=' + this.client_secret)
.map(res => res.json());
```

to get a list of repositories for the chosen user (without using GraphQL).

How can I get a list of issues but by using GraphQL?
Here is an example grom GitHub API documentation:

```
query {
  repository(owner:"octocat", name:"Hello-World") {
    issues(last:20, states:CLOSED) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          url
          labels(first:5) {
            edges {
              node {
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I implement it in Angular 4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are at least two ways:

- Using GraphQL client like `apollo-angular`
- Fetching data from GraphQL API using a simple HTTP request

**Use HTTP**

```
const query = `query {
  repository(owner:"octocat", name:"Hello-World") {
    issues(last:20, states:CLOSED) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          url
          labels(first:5) {
            edges {
              node {
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`;

this._http.get(LINK_TO_API + '?query=' + query);
```

**Use `apollo-angular`**

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-angular

Apollo is a GraphQL client.

Here are the docs:

http://dev.apollodata.com/angular2/

An example:

```
import { Apollo } from 'apollo-angular';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

@Component({
    /* ... */
})
class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private apollo: Apollo
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        // or this.apollo.watchQuery() - read the docs
        this.apollo.query({
            query: gql`
                {
                    repository(owner: "octocat", name: "Hello-World") {
                        issues(last:20, states:CLOSED) {
                            edges {
                                node {
                                    title
                                    url
                                    labels(first:5) {
                                        edges {
                                            node {
                                                name
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            `
        }).subscribe(response => {
            console.log('data', response.data);
        });
    }
}
```

A working examples:

https://github.com/kamilkisiela/apollo-angular-reproduction/blob/master/client/app/post/post-list.component.ts

https://github.com/apollographql/githunt-angular

Comment: Thanks but I have an error now.

http://localhost:4200/graphql [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 2 ms]
ERROR Error: Network error: Network request failed with status 404 - "Not Found"

Comment: You have to specify a proper URL in the NetworkInterface